# Bind a function to Twitter Bootstrap Modal Ajax Complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I use this for Bootstrap Modal:

```
<a href="one/url" data-target="#add-follow-up-modal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">                 
    Load
</a>
<div id="add-follow-up-modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Please wait…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, i want to run a function when ajax load completed.

Any idea?

Comment: what do you use to make the ajax call?

Comment: where is your ajax call .

Comment: when i set href in the link, bootstrap load `one/url` automatically and put's to `modal-body`

Answer (score 3):

By default bootstrap modal does not trigger an event for ajax load, you can have a look at the list of triggered events at the modal section of the bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals).

What you can do, however is to write your own function that loads the content to the modal's body via ajax, and attach a .done() to it.

Comment: thanks.
i try this:
`$('#my-modal').on('shown', function () {
 $.get( "one/url", function( data ) {
  $('.modal-body').html(data);
  //do somethings that i want
 });
});`

Answer (score 0):

remove href from your link

in ajax success add `href="one/url"` to your "a" attributes and then trigger click on your link